# Developing A Three Column Layout in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am looking to make a three column layout for my posts in wordpress similar to the three column layout on this site [Onlythebest.co](http://Onlythebest.co). Can anyone direct me to a good plugin that would help me to develop a three column layout or suggest the best approach to create a three column layout in wordpress? I do not have any code at this point to share, I have researching the best way to accomplish developing a three column grid in wordpress at this point.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More commonly, you'll be able to look for a theme to accomplish what you're after.. You can find a free or premium theme that offers this built-in to it's core. Look on **wordpress.org for free themes**, or you can look for **premium themes at codecanyon.net**

If you are designing a custom theme, or trying to implement your 3-column grid into an existing theme, you can use a free drag-and-drop plugin that makes it very easy to accomplish your goal.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/siteorigin-panels/screenshots/

It also makes it easy to utilize the widgetized areas inside of the columns/rows.

A premium page builder with much more scalibilty and advanced functionality would be Visual Composer sold at CodeCanyon for $30.  This builder is incorporated in some of the top tier themes as well, so you can look for themes while your on CodeCanyon.

http://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431

---

For manual markup, you'll need atleast 4 `<div>` containers.
And then use css to make your styling code to format the columns.

## HTML ##

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="leftcol">left</div>
    <div class="middlecol">middle</div>
    <div class="rightcol">right</div>wrapper
</div>
```

## CSS ##

```
 .wrapper {
        width:100%;
        height:400px;
        padding:6px;
        /*you can remove this, only for visualization purposes*/
        background-color:black;
        /*you can remove this, only for visualization purposes*/
    }
    .leftcol, .middlecol, .rightcol {
        width:33%;
        height:400px;
        display:block;
        float:left;
    }
    .leftcol {
        background-color:green;
    }
    .rightcol {
        background-color:red;
    }
    .middlecol {
        background-color:blue;
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to add the quick demo I put together for you which uses the code above.  http://jsfiddle.net/r4t2F/